# Determining the hexadecimal values of an address of a little endian machine

Tags: c, endianness, machine-code

I am a bit confused on how you would approach this problem:

Consider decimal number 1027. This value is stored as a 16-bit two's complement number into addresses 124 and 125 on a little endian machine which has an addressable cell size of one byte. What values (in hexadecimal) are in each of these addresses:

124:

125:

I know that a little endian machine orders it addresses from the least significant byte to the most significant byte. But besides from that I am unsure of how you would apply that concept and how you would order bytes into the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple Python code to convert that integer to little-endian hexadecimal representation:

```
# convert the integer (1027) to hex using 2 bytes and little-endian byteorder
(1027).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='little').hex()
```

This gives `0304`. So, the first byte (`03`) is in address 124 and the second one (`04`) occupies the next address - 125.

Answer (score 0):

"Little endian" and "big endian" relate to how the machine multiplexes bytes from memory into registers of the CPU.

With each byte it gets, it increments the address counter, but does it place these bytes from left-to-right or right-to-left into the register?

So the address that gets loaded into a machine register (or an integer), can be stored reverse in the memory. Even with modern CPUs with broad data busses, the concept remained and in some CPUs the bytes get swapped inside the CPU.